# Power BI: Is there a way to create a group with a measure?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

lets say I have the following data set:

| Country | Sales Team | Sales Division | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peru | A | South America | 1 | 12 |
| Peru | B | South America | 1 | 23 |
| Peru | C | South America | 1 | 12 |
| Peru | D | South America | 1 | 32 |
| Chile | A | South America | 1 | 231 |
| Chile | B | South America | 1 | 32 |
| Chile | C | South America | 1 | 21 |
| Chile | D | South America | 1 | 321 |
| Canada | A | North America | 1 | 33 |
| Canada | B | North America | 1 | 54 |
| Canada | C | North America | 1 | 22 |
| Canada | D | North America | 1 | 12 |
| France | A | Europe | 1 | 32 |
| France | B | Europe | 1 | 321 |
| France | C | Europe | 1 | 534 |
| France | D | Europe | 1 | 321 |
| Peru | A | South America | 2 | 321 |
| Peru | B | South America | 2 | 2323 |
| Peru | C | South America | 2 | 1244 |
| Peru | D | South America | 2 | 3221 |

I want to create a matrix like this:

[image]

For column there is the Sales Team and then the month. I would like to modify the column for Sales Team, not only showing A,B,C,D. I would like to show sth like A, B, A&B, C, D, C&D. The value is also the sum between 2 Sales teams.

Is this possible with using a measure instead of doing it in Power Query?

Thanks!